# Where to find CSV or JSON data for publicly traded companies listed with their IPO date?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, historical-data, ipo

I found some of this data on Nasdaq's website, but a third of the IPO dates were listed as "n/a".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its more about writing a software code.

Comment: Great. So if I put it in the SO section, someone will vote to close because the question only relates to finding data rather than a question about how to solve a coding problem.

Comment: Pretty much. I guess it isn't really on topic for either site. Maybe try this site's chat room (or SO's) the "on topic" filters are looser in there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list to Yahoo! Finance API.  Not sure how much longer this will be support though:

https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/YahooFinanceAPIs